# Jquery name selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

got this problem:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fasdf" value="1" id="dsasd" ></input>
<input type="checkbox" name="fasdf" value="2" id="hjiuhhjb" ></input>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/asdf/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var numberChecked = jQuery("input[name='fasdf']").length;
    alert(numberChecked);
    jQuery("input[name='fasdf']").attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

numberChecked always returns 1, and the first checkbox is checked. If I change the name of the first checkbox, then the second one is checked. Why?

Thanks in advance

EDITED: FUNCTION REMOVED

Comment: return 2 here for length http://jsfiddle.net/LMj7q/

Comment: Yeah so I just do not understand. May be I have some strange JS code somewhere.

Comment: would be great if you can create the fiddle.

Comment: where did you call documento function? function didn't call in this code block.

Comment: OK guys, the problem is chromium portable doing something wrong. Working on IE8. Thanks everybody :)

Comment: you must wrap your js to $(document).ready function......

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you gave the same name to the checkboxes.
Some jQuery functions target only the first matched element (in your case you're targetting more than one).
When you change the first checkbox name, then the only checkbox targetted is `#hjiuhhjb`.
Here a simple solution:

```
jQuery("input[name='fasdf']").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

`.each()` will iterate over all elements matched (more: [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/))